# Navigating hierarchical data, FrameAdapter, Frame control

Tags: mvvm, tree, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, caliburn.micro

I want to implement navigating a tree structure like it is done in e.g. the WinRT file picker. I then want to be able to drop this behavior as part of any page.

My current attempt, is to try and register a secondary `FrameAdapter`/`INavigationService` in the container and use that for a frame that is different from the app root frame. So far, I could not get it to work.
My motivation behind that, is, that I do not want to reimplement sth. that the `INavigationService` already provides.

Basic structure:

- `ShellView` that represents the general app layout (header, footer, navigation) and is currently an `OneActive` conductor.
- `Frame` control (`x:Name="ActiveItem"`) on the `ShellView` inside which the hierarchical navigation should occur
- The chosen conductor has no relevance yet, since I'll probably have to nest the `FrameControl` inside another view later to really set up a MDI interface. I'll will want to have multiple screens that should be able to hierarchically navigate

I could not find a CM WP7 example of such a scenario

Can you help me out here?

My problems so far:

- How do I access the container from a view code-behind without resorting to using the `Application.Current`. I figured, it is in the code-behind where I would want to setup the secondary `FrameAdapter`, since it is here that I have access to the `FrameControl`
- How do I setup the `INavigationService` so that the initial loading by CM (populating the `ActiveItem`) is registered with it. There does not seem to be a navigation event for this initial display of the `ActiveItem`.

Many thanks in advance,

Tobias

PS: I have cross-posted to the Caliburn Micro discussions ([Discussion over at CodePlex CM](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/398445))

Comment: I did something, not in RT, similar with CM and the telerik TreeControl.  This helped to start out: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode